# Query is not executing in android N

Tags: android, image, retrofit, android-7.1-nougat

The following code is working on 6.0.1 and lower versions, but in android 7.0 is always gone to onFailure() function. Log cat not showing any kind of error.

class ServiceResult.java

```
public static void updateUser(final int type,final String id,
                                      final String relation_status,
                                      final  String height,
                                      final String weight,
                                      final  String want_to_lose_weight,
                                      final String excercise_time,
                                      final  String diet_plan,
                                      final  String excercise_program,
                                      final  String ethnicity,
                                      final String about_yourself,final String path,final String moreImage,final String message,final String smiley,final String ZIP,final String kind_of_diet_pal,
                                      final String fitness_trcker,
                                      final String goals) {
            Call<RegisterResponce> responseCall = ServiceConnection.getInstance().updateUser(id, relation_status, height,
                    weight, want_to_lose_weight, excercise_time,
                    diet_plan, excercise_program, ethnicity, about_yourself, path, moreImage, message, smiley, ZIP, kind_of_diet_pal, fitness_trcker, goals);
            responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<RegisterResponce>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<RegisterResponce> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

                    Log.e("Code ", response.code() + "");
                    if (response.code() == 200) {
                        Log.e("Result   ", response.body().getResponse().getMessage() + "");
                        if (type == 0) {
                            FunctionUtils.stopProgressDialog();
                            UPDATE_OBSERVER.setResponse(response.body());
                        } else if (type == 1) {
                            FunctionUtils.stopProgressDialog();
                            ServiceResult.userProfile(0, SharedPref.getInt(Constant.PREF_USER_ID) + "", SharedPref.getInt(Constant.PREF_USER_ID) + "");
                            Log.i("****",String.valueOf(response.code()));
                            Edit.getInstance().SetDataAfterUpdate(response.code());
                            //Toast.makeText(act,"data successfully updated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    FunctionUtils.stopProgressDialog();
                    Log.e("Upload pic", t.getLocalizedMessage());
                    FunctionUtils.showToast("please try again");
                }
            });

                }
            };

        }
```

Class ServiceConnection.java
updateUser(...)  method is following.

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("krista2522/ws/api.php?action=update_profile")
    Call<RegisterResponce> updateUser(@Field("id") String id,
                                      @Field("relation_status") String relation_status,
                                      @Field("height") String height,
                                      @Field("weight") String weight,
                                      @Field("want_to_lose_weight") String want_to_lose_weight,
                                      @Field("excercise_time") String excercise_time,
                                      @Field("diet_plan") String diet_plan,
                                      @Field("excercise_program") String excercise_program,
                                      @Field("ethnicity") String ethnicity,
                                      @Field("about_yourself") String about_yourself,
                                      @Field("user_image") String user_image,
                                      @Field("user_more_image") String user_more_image,
                                      @Field("messages") String messages,
                                      @Field("smiles") String smiles,
                                      @Field("zip") String zip,
                                      @Field("kind_of_diet_pal") String kind_of_diet_pal,
                                      @Field("fitness_tracker")   String fitness_tracker,
                                      @Field("goals")    String goals        );
```

I'm calling updateUser() method in my Profile.java activity as

```
ServiceResult.updateUser(0, PREF_USER_ID + "", RELATION_STATUS, FEET + " ft " +
                        INCHES + " inch", WEIGHT, WEIGHT_LOSS, EXERCISE, DIET_PLAN, EXERCISE_PLAN, ETHNICITY, ABOUTUS, PATH, "", "", "", ZIP, KIND_PAL, FITNESS_TRACKER, GOALS);
```